# Has ADM(X) template become mandatory when deploying Foxit Reader?

Tags: group-policy

In a couple of AD environments there has been no reason to centrally modify or force any setting of Foxit Reader. Therefore, while the Foxit Reader has been deployed via Group Policy using the MSI package (provided by Foxit Software Inc. for this purpose), the group policy templates (`.adm` / `.admx`) were never used. Foxit Reader installed & updated nicely (via *Computer Configuration > Policies > Software Settings > Software installation*) and worked just fine for years.

Lately (I'd say versions > 8.0) there has been more problems after updates: occasionally the Foxit Reader prompts for UAC when a user starts it. I believe there shouldn't be anything that would need elevated rights, since Foxit Reader starts just fine even if the UAC prompt is closed. The main problem here is the reduced user experience (and all the unnecessary helpdesk tickets).

Has anyone here already researched this? What is it trying to modify? Will using the group policy template (or a particular setting in it) prevent Foxit Reader from doing this? Or would it be possible to just change/add some registry key that would satisfy Foxit Reader on its startup?

Comment: My guess would be it is launching some auto-update component. If it is reproducible, run SysInternals Process Monitor to see what executable is launched or resource is accessed that is causing the UAC prompt. Also, is the UAC prompt displayed if installed manually?

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking if someone has already done this research, because it might take some time to be able to log this activity. I think it happens on the first start after an update, but haven't yet been able to reproduce this. Starting `procmon.exe` when the UAC has already been prompted doesn't give this information, and the UAC prompt disappears after the first start.

Comment: I finally figured this out. :)

Comment: @GregAskew: Using Process Monitor wasn't very useful, since there was so much unrelated activity, like `RegSetValue` for every setting when closing preferences! Only way to solve this was to perform two exports from `regedit` and compare them with `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still possible to maintain Foxit Reader deployment without the ADM template, but it would have made solving this a lot easier. Here's a solution both with and without using the ADM template.

### CAUSE

It seems that the UAC prompt is caused when Foxit Reader checks whether it's the default viewer for PDF files or not and the user answers [Yes]. (Naturally users never remember answering...)

[image: Foxit Reader default PDF prompt]

While this modification of default application occurs even without elevated privileges i.e. answering [Yes] only modifies registry keys inside `HKCU`, for some reason Foxit Reader prompts for UAC.

---

### SOLUTION 1 with Foxit Reader ADM template:

Foxit ADM template has in *Foxit Reader > Preferences >*:

- *Default PDF Viewer* – sets Foxit Reader as the default PDF viewer.
- *Forbid Checking of Default PDF Viewer* – hides the 'Set to Default PDF Reader' dialog.

---

### SOLUTION 2 without the ADM template:

You can also get rid of this message without using the group policy template, so it's not mandatory to install the template. The registry key controlling the behavior of this dialog is

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader 8.0\Preferences\Others]
"bCheckRegister"="0"
```

- `"bCheckRegister"="0"` for hiding the dialog
- `"bCheckRegister"="1"` for showing the dialog

This should be updated with GPO *User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry* as it is a key inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

---

### Disabling Foxit Updater

Foxit Reader also has an automated update tool, Foxit Updater. If you are updating Foxit Reader via GPO, you probably don't want it to check for updates by itself as an update would also require elevated privileges, also causing UAC prompts for your users. (Thanks, Greg Askew!)

The easiest way of disabling Foxit Updater is not to install it at all. Foxit [Enterprise Packaging](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/enterprise-register.php) has, along with the group policy templates, a **Foxit Customization Tool** that enables you to create a *Windows Installer Setup Transform* `.mst` file to use with GP managed software installation.

- On General, there's an Additional Task, [x] Disable Auto Update.
- On Features, there's an Additional Setting, [x] Don't Install Foxit Updater.